# drop downlist selected value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
ddlType.DataSource = ObjComplaintReportFormBLL.ComplaintType();
      ddlType.DataTextField = "ComplaintType_Name";
      ddlType.DataValueField = "complainttype_id";
      ddlType.DataBind();
     ddlType.Items.Insert(0, "All");
```

ObjComplaintReportFormBLL.ComplaintType() returns the ComplaintType_Name, complainttype_id

All is the default value for the drop down list  Now how should I set the value of this list item "All" to 0(int)
    I could do 
 `ddlType.Items[0].value = "0".` But this is a string

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ddlType.Items.Insert(0, "All");
```

with

```
ddlType.Items.Add(new ListItem(0,"All"));
```

Comment: This will add listitem at the end of dropdownlist items, since he need to insert at 0 index of dropdownlist items.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: But how should I set the value of the listitem which is being inserted. The default item-All has a selected value 0

Comment: Did you try my solution, I am asking you need to add listitem object, which have value and text properties that I have set and added.

Comment: ddlType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0")); I was able to do it

Comment: so what's an issue, it is fine.

Comment: SelectedValue/Value is String type property. whenever you want to retrieve the value you will get String value and then you can convert that value to Int. e.g. Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the listItem object to the `ddlType.Items.Insert` method instead of passing a string value e.g.

```
ListItem liItem = new ListItem("All","0");
ddlType.Items.Insert(0,liItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `Insert`, you're putting the text "All" as the first option in the dropdown with a value of "" (empty string).  To get "0" to be your value for your "All" item, provide a `ListItem`:

```
ddlType.Items.Add(new ListItem("0", "All"));
```

or, perhaps closer to what you want to do, this will insert your "All" item at the start of the list:

```
ddlType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("0", "All"));
```

then:

```
ddlType.SelectedValue = "0";
```